# Java/ Remove a Integer value from a list

Tags: java, collections

I have the following lists of Integer

```
whatToRemove = {2, 3, 8};
```

and another list

```
lst = {4, 6, 8}
```

I want to remove all `whatToRemove` the elements from `lst`.

I am trying to use `lst.remove(whatToRemove.get(i))`, but it is trying to remove the index, and not the value.

How can I do that?

Comment: try list.removeAll(whatToRemove);

Comment: @jeppi answered it. Btw, I don't how, but it appears as if in your case `whatToRemove.get(i)` is treated as an `int`, that's why it is used as an index. If you put that piece within a `Integer.valueOf(...)` then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Integer> whatToRemove = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 8);
    List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4, 6, 8));
    lst.removeAll(whatToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), which takes an object that implements the [`Collection interface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) as the parameter like this:

```
list.removeAll(collection);
```

Or you need do some sort of iteration in order to go through all of the values as you want to remove as [`remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) doesn't take another list as a parameter, only an index or an object:

```
for(int i=0;i<whatToRemove.size();i++){
lst.remove(whatToRemove.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iterator:

```
for (Iterator it=lst.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
   if (whatToRemove.contains(it.next())
      it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Java collections to do this, you can simply call `removeAll(Collection<T> o)` on your first list to remove all occurences.

it would look like `lst.removeAll(whatToRemove);`

Alternatively you can iterate over all elements easily

```
for(int num : whatToRemove)
{
     lst.remove(num);
}
```

Both are viable, if you are using arrays, you can still use the enhanced for to iterate. but removing is a different problem.

Link to Javadoc: [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is because a List has a remove that removes an element by index and a remove that removes by object see:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)

See how there are 2 removes :-(?

Unfortunately as your list contains integers Java thinks that you mean remove( item at) and not remove(object)

Use

```
Collection lst = [whatever]
lst.remove(whatToRemove.get(i))
```

...and then the remove should work correctly as Collection only has 1 kind of remove function (the one you want to use)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the removeAll method on List

Answer (score 0):

With the list element you are going to want to remove the index of the objects within the list. For your example it will be integers obviously. To accomplish this you can used a for loop or pull each indexed object out in a manual way.

for loop - example :

```
for(int i = 0; i < whatToRemove.size(); i++){
     whatToRemove.remove(i);
 }
```

manual - example :

```
whatToRemove.remove(0);
whatToRemove.remove(1);
whatToRemove.remove(2);
```

This is from what I am understanding from your question that you would like to remove all the elements from your list call "whatToRemove".

Here is a link that may provide some insight into the list parameters [Link - Java Object 'List'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **removeAll(Collection c)** method as shown below

***lst.removeAll(whatToRemove);***

Please check the sample below

```
List<Integer> whatToRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
whatToRemove.add(new Integer(2));
whatToRemove.add(new Integer(3));
whatToRemove.add(new Integer(8));

List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lst.add(new Integer(4));
lst.add(new Integer(6));
lst.add(new Integer(8));

lst.removeAll(whatToRemove);
```

you can refer to below URL for more details on collection and removeAll method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html